# SSL requests fail intermittently on iOS 8.0 but works fine on iOS 7.0 apps

Tags: ios

We are using *ClientCertificate authentication for SSL requests*. This is working fine in **iOS 7.0** but fails randomly on iOS 8.0.

The error message is

> NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9846) 2014-09-30 12:27:29.517
>   login response Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
>   Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the
>   server cannot be made." UserInfo=0x7fce4bf0ced0
>   {NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
>   anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9846,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7fce4bd2b9b0 "An SSL error has occurred and a
>   secure connection to the server cannot be made.",
>   NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure
>   connection to the server cannot be made.

Any help regarding this would be really helpful.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446175/why-ios8-ssl-requests-fail-intermittently-after-migration-from-ios7)?

Comment: I had seen this, but just wanted to be sure if it is really an apple bug. Any help on this would be helpful.